# Get updates from telegram channel

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

Is it possible to get updates from channel via Telegram API without adding a bot to this channel?

I am building bot which can automatically save posts from subscribed channels (i mean channels to which user subscribes with a command in bot itself) in case they are deleted by author and i am stucked on how to get updates from channels.

I read a lot of different information about this problem but i still not sure is there any ways to do this (via webhooks or something else)?

P.S I know that i can make a scraper which will retrieve channel posts from html but its slow and not convenient